# query to return a day's records from datetime field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

In a spring mvc application using hibernate and jpa, I have a query that needs to return all the records whose date falls within a specified day.  The day comes ultimately from a url parameter in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and is stored in a joda `localdate` object.  The entity whose records are searched by day has joda `DateTime` as the type for the property being searched.  The underlying MySQL database has the date information stored in a [TimeStamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) field.  In order to convert from `localdate` to `datetime`, I read [the localdate api](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) and tried `day.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()`, but this narrows the parameter too far.  I need to get all records within the 24 hour period of the day, not just those in the first second of the day.  How can I structure the query so that it returns every record from the `TimeStamp` field with a specified day, including all times within that specified day?

Here is the method containing the query in the jpa repository:

```
@Override
public Collection<Encounter> findByDay(LocalDate day){
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ made it into findByDay()");
    DateTime myDT = day.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT encounter FROM Encounter encounter WHERE encounter.dateTime LIKE :day");
    query.setParameter("day", myDT);
    return query.getResultList();       
}
```

Here is the sql for the underlying datatable in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS encounters(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  patient_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  office_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  provider_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  start_date TIMESTAMP,
  status varchar(50),
  FOREIGN KEY (patient_id) REFERENCES patients(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (office_id) REFERENCES facilityAddresses(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (provider_id) REFERENCES providers(id)
)engine=InnoDB;
```

And here is the relevant part of the `Encounter` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "encounters")
public class Encounter extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name="start_date")
    private DateTime dateTime;

    //other mappings of columns to properties

    // getters and setters

}
```

---

### EDIT:

Here is what I am testing based on Affe's suggestion:

```
@Override
public Collection<Encounter> findByDay(LocalDate day){
    System.out.println("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk inside repository.findByDay()  ");
    DateTime startDay = day.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
    DateTime startNextDay = startDay.plusDays(1);
    System.out.println("startDay is: "+startDay);
    System.out.println("startNextDay is: "+startNextDay);
    Query query = this.em.createQuery(
        "SELECT DISTINCT encounter " +
        "FROM Encounter encounter " +
        "WHERE encounter.dateTime >= :startDay and encounter.dateTime < :startNextDay");
    query.setParameter("startDay", startDay);
    query.setParameter("startNextDay", startNextDay);
    Collection<Encounter> myresult = query.getResultList();
    Object[] something = myresult.toArray();
    System.out.println("vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv num results is: "+myresult.size());
    for(int i=0;i<something.length;i++){
        System.out.println("nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn "+something[i].toString());
    }
    return myresult;
}
```

Here is the sql that inserts test data into the database:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO encounters VALUES (1, 5, 2, 1, '2013-11-30 09:00:00','Active');
INSERT IGNORE INTO encounters VALUES (2, 4, 1, 2, '2013-12-15 10:00:00','Inactive');
INSERT IGNORE INTO encounters VALUES (3, 3, 4, 3, '2014-1-10 11:00:00','Active');
INSERT IGNORE INTO encounters VALUES (4, 2, 3, 4, '2014-1-13 12:00:00','Inactive');
INSERT IGNORE INTO encounters VALUES (5, 1, 1, 3, '2014-1-12 13:00:00','Inactive');
```

When I select `2014-1-10`, `2014-1-13`, `2014-1-12` or the other inserted dates as parameters, the `system.out.println()` above prints out zero for the number of results, so the for loop never runs.  The query should return a result for each of those days.

For example, when I select `2014-1-10`, the following is output in the eclipse console:

```
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk inside repository.findByDay()  
startDay is: 2014-01-10T00:00:00.000-08:00
startNextDay is: 2014-01-11T00:00:00.000-08:00
Hibernate: select distinct encounter0_.id as id1_10_, encounter0_.start_date as start2_10_, encounter0_.office_id as office4_10_, encounter0_.patient_id as patient5_10_, encounter0_.status as status3_10_ from encounters encounter0_ where encounter0_.start_date>=? and encounter0_.start_date<?
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv num results is: 0
number of encounters is: 0
aaaa hours of day, mins of hour for block: 8, 0
aaaa hours of day, mins of hour for block: 9, 0
aaaa hours of day, mins of hour for block: 10, 0
aaaa hours of day, mins of hour for block: 11, 0
aaaa hours of day, mins of hour for block: 12, 0
aaaa hours of day, mins of hour for block: 13, 0
aaaa hours of day, mins of hour for block: 14, 0
aaaa hours of day, mins of hour for block: 15, 0
aaaa hours of day, mins of hour for block: 16, 0
```

Does the format of the `datetime` output by `System.out.println()` have anything to do with the problem?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was very simple.  I just needed to add `@Type` annotation to the `Encounter` entity's `dateTime` field as follows:

```
@Column(name="start_date")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime dateTime;
```

My original jpa/sql code works fine after adding this one line of code to the entity.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to query for a range.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search over the range of all timestamps that fall on the particular day.  Functionality for treating a timestamp as a date within the database is DB specific and not available through the JPA API.  (and often a bad idea anyway unless you've built a functional index based on the date values.)

```
@Override
public Collection<Encounter> findByDay(LocalDate day){
    DateTime startDay = day.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
    DateTime startNextDay = startDay.plusDays(1);
    Query query = this.em.createQuery(
        "SELECT DISTINCT encounter " +
        "FROM Encounter encounter " +
        "WHERE encounter.dateTime >= :startDay and encounter.dateTime < :startNextDay");
    query.setParameter("startDay", startDay);
    query.setParameter("startNextDay", startNextDay);
    return query.getResultList();       
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I haven't actually used hibernate + joda much.  Did you try  `query.setParameter("startDay", startDay.toDate());
    query.setParameter("startNextDay", startNextDay.toDate());` ?

Comment: adding .toDate() in the places you suggested resulted in the following error: `Parameter value [Fri Jan 10 00:00:00 PST 2014] did not match expected type [org.joda.time.DateTime]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Fri Jan 10 00:00:00 PST 2014] did not match expected type [org.joda.time.DateTime]`

Comment: I have another related question.  Are you willing to help me solve it?  here is the link to the new posting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002272/entity-relationship-not-populating-properly

Answer (score 0):

I thing the problem is in date formats

You store date in your database in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` *(i.e 2013-11-30 09:00:00)*  format 
and you are passig date in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` *(i.e 2014-01-10T00:00:00.000-08:00)* format to query

first you have to convert your LocalDate in given format as

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate(2010, 9, 14);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String startDay = formatter.print(localDate);
```

then you have to set it to query parameter

```
Query query = this.em.createQuery(
    "SELECT DISTINCT encounter " +
    "FROM Encounter encounter " +
    "WHERE encounter.dateTime = "+ startDay +"");
```

hope this will solve your problem !

Comment: Your approach caused the following runtime error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2014-02-10 00:00:00] did not match expected type [org.joda.time.DateTime]` . The error is localized at the following line of code: `query.setParameter("startDay", startDay);` Have you got any other suggestions?

Comment: `query.setParameter("startDay", startDay);` should sort you.