# entity relationship not populating properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In a Spring MVC application using Hibernate, a list that joins two entities in a ManyToMany relationship is not populating properly.  The entities are `Encounter` and `Provider`.  The `Encounter` entity has a property `providers`, which is a list of `Property` entities, and which is not populating properly.  Can someone help me figure out how to fix my code so that the entity starts to populate properly?

The code for the controller method that fails to properly populate the ArrayList is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/calendar")
public String showCalendar(@RequestParam("day") String day, org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest webRequest, Model model) {
    String pid = webRequest.getParameter("pid");
    System.out.println("............ pid is:  " + pid);

    model.addAttribute("pid", pid);
    LocalDate mydate;

    if(day.equals("")) {
      mydate = new LocalDate();
    } else {
      mydate = new LocalDate(day);
    }

    System.out.println("------------------------ in controller, day of month is:  " + mydate.getDayOfMonth());
    AppointmentCalendar calendar = new AppointmentCalendar(mydate); // Or whatever you do to create it
    List<Encounter> encountersforday = (List<Encounter>) clinicService.getEncountersForDay(mydate);

    model.addAttribute("calendar", calendar);
    model.addAttribute("encountersforday", encountersforday);

    System.out.println("number of encountersforday is: " + encountersforday.size());

    List<LocalTime> myblocks = calendar.getBlocks();
    int[][] filledblocks = new int[myblocks.size()][3];
    for (Integer i=0; i < encountersforday.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("i, encounterid, patientid, first, last, " +
                           "numProviders, dateTime are: " + i + ", " +
                           encountersforday.get(i).getId() + ", " +
                           encountersforday.get(i).getPatient().getId() + ", " +
                           encountersforday.get(i).getPatient().getFirstName() + ", " +
                           encountersforday.get(i).getPatient().getLastName() + ", " +
                           encountersforday.get(i).getProviders().size() + ", " +
                           encountersforday.get(i).getDateTime());
        for (Integer g=0; g < myblocks.size(); g++) {
            filledblocks[g][0] = g;//blockid
            if (myblocks.get(g).getHourOfDay() == encountersforday.get(i).getDateTime().getHourOfDay()) {
                if (myblocks.get(g).getMinuteOfHour() == encountersforday.get(i).getDateTime().getMinuteOfHour()) {
                    int hours = myblocks.get(g).getHourOfDay();
                    int mins = myblocks.get(g).getMinuteOfHour();
                    System.out.println("found match at: "+hours+":"+mins);
                    filledblocks[g][1] = i+1;//encounterid
                    filledblocks[g][2] = 1;//segmentindex
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return "appointments/calendar";
}
```

The `System.out.println()` commands in the preceding code output the following:

```
number of encountersforday is: 5
i, encounterid, patientid, first, last, numProviders, dateTime are: 0, 1, 5, Peter, McTavish, 0, 2014-01-10T12:00:00.000-08:00
found match at: 12:0
i, encounterid, patientid, first, last, numProviders, dateTime are: 1, 2, 4, Harold, Davis, 0, 2014-01-10T11:30:00.000-08:00
found match at: 11:30
i, encounterid, patientid, first, last, numProviders, dateTime are: 2, 3, 3, Eduardo, Rodriquez, 0, 2014-01-10T10:00:00.000-08:00
found match at: 10:0
i, encounterid, patientid, first, last, numProviders, dateTime are: 3, 4, 2, Morticia, Adams, 0, 2014-01-10T09:30:00.000-08:00
found match at: 9:30
i, encounterid, patientid, first, last, numProviders, dateTime are: 4, 5, 1, Speed, Racer, 1, 2014-01-10T13:30:00.000-08:00
found match at: 13:30
```

As you can see from the output above, only one of the `Encounter` objects has greater than 0 `numProviders`.  This is true despite the fact that every single one of the `Encounters` has a `Provider` specified in the underlying data table.

**NOTE: To simplify this posting, I have uploaded the relevant code to a file sharing site.  You can view the code at the file sharing site by clicking on the links below.**

You can read the code for creating and populating the data tables for `encounters` and `providers` in the underlying database [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/dpfMw1GcxxT1idRnY33k?b=A5eFdd6NIzfK4THR6ywm).

The code for the `Encounter` entity is [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/HZa6rUaQ2rYT6fZFUGqD?b=5kGXnbu644ibC8sVfoQU).

The code for the `Provider` entity is [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/VBnvLj5cmo30xU0uwcig?b=XC7I8NrZgJjMGfpcY5bL).

The code for `BaseEntity` is [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/rYHzIV7P3fQKZ4qEalZD?b=ndIjMOqNwwx0mryvcvHM).

The code for the `Person` entity is [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/4sdK4xTom7mW1kC5JV0g?b=tBqbKukTRbNlUYM0Dio5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every insert into the `providerEncounterJunction` table uses the same primary key.  I would guess they are simply overwriting each other and you only really have one row in that table.

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to catch that obvious error buried deep in the code.